# Using mdadm to perform no-downtime backupd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, raid, mdadm

I have a server running Ubuntu 23.10. It contains several RAID 1 arrays created using mdadm. One of these holds the virtual machine disk images of my web-servers. Currently, to backup these images, I have to stop the VM, copy the file using rsync, and then restart the VM. This process takes about 10 minutes.
What I would like to be able to do is remove one disk from the relevant RAID array, mount it separately, copy the data, then add the disk to the RAID array again (and resync, obviously). This is similar to the backup procedure that we used to use in a previous job, where the system had hardware RAID, and would allow backups with no downtime of the web-server VMs.
I cannot find any guidance on this in any of the online forums, but I am sure it must be possible.

Comment: Killing your array is awful for your disks and general performance - it's going to trigger a full consistency scan and possibly rebuild every time. There are much better ways to handle backups, depending on your VM manager and filesystem. If you want to roll your own, you could take an lvm snapshot, mount it, copy your vms from there, then delete it.